# How do you set a GitLab CI variable to an array in gitlab-ci?

Tags: arrays, bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to create a gitlab variable using the `variables:` keyword that contains an array of dependencies to pass to the GitLab `dependencies:` keyword. The structure would look something like:

```
variables:
    DEPENDENCY_LIST: ["dependency1", "dependency2", "dependency3"]

dependencies: "$DEPENDENCY_LIST"
```

But the above code gives a YAML error saying that "jobs:source code dependencies should be an array of strings"

How can I set the value of a GitLab CI variable to an array in a .gitlab-ci.yml job?

Answer (score 4):

> How do you set a GitLab CI variable to an array in gitlab-ci?

You can't - environment variables are in the form name=value. There are no arrays.

Use yaml anchors.

```
.dependency_list: &dependency_list
   - dependency1
   - dependency2
   - dependency3

dependencies: *dependency_list
```

However gitlab-ci does not flatten nested arrays in dependencies, so there is no way to merge two arrays.

See gitlab ci documentation.